# How to centre a uiview in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I want to centre a uiview in Xcode but it is not working. I can't
seem to get it right.

[screenshot of what I am doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnYtx.png)

[screenshot of the the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qYjU.jpg)

Please I don't understand these. Please, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Horizolly in Container, Vertically in Container.[image]

Comment: Please, I have added alignment to the app, but the container did not show at runtime.

Comment: how did you set view width & height.?
it seems u arranged view height based on top view, but it won't work I guess.
either you have to set it as static or ration with super view.

Comment: In the Size Inspector;
I used "Frame Rectangle" in the _Show_ dropdown.
58 for _X_ field
345 for _Y_ field
279 for Width
and 307 for Height.